# How to find a text and replace it with an image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I have this code which searches for a text and replace it with an another text in MS word document. I want to do the similar kind of operation. Find the text and replace it with an image. I can pass the file location, image location.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    //using System.Drawing;


    namespace WritingIntoDocx
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public interface IMyClass
        {

          void DocumentDigitalSign(string filep,string findt,string replacet);
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]

       public class Program : IMyClass
        {
             public void DocumentDigitalSign(string filep, string findt, string replacet)
            {
                string filepath = filep;
                string Findtext = findt;
                string ReplaceText = replacet;
                word.Application app = new word.Application();
                word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filepath);

                word.Range myStoryRange = doc.Range();

                //First search the main document using the Selection
                word.Find myFind = myStoryRange.Find;
                myFind.Text = Findtext;
                myFind.Replacement.Text = ReplaceText;
                //myFind.Replacement.
                myFind.Forward = true;
                myFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                myFind.Format = false;
                myFind.MatchCase = false;
                myFind.MatchWholeWord = false;
                myFind.MatchWildcards = false;
                myFind.MatchSoundsLike = false;
                myFind.MatchAllWordForms = false;
                myFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

                //'Now search all other stories using Ranges
                foreach (word.Range otherStoryRange in doc.StoryRanges)
                {
                    if (otherStoryRange.StoryType != word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory)
                    {
                        word.Find myOtherFind = otherStoryRange.Find;
                        myOtherFind.Text = Findtext;
                        myOtherFind.Replacement.Text = ReplaceText;
                        myOtherFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                        myOtherFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
                    }

                    // 'Now search all next stories of other stories (doc.storyRanges dont seem to cascades in sub story)
                    word.Range nextStoryRange = otherStoryRange.NextStoryRange;
                    while (nextStoryRange != null)
                    {
                        word.Find myNextStoryFind = nextStoryRange.Find;
                        myNextStoryFind.Text = Findtext;
                        myNextStoryFind.Replacement.Text = ReplaceText;
                        myNextStoryFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                        myNextStoryFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

                        nextStoryRange = nextStoryRange.NextStoryRange;
                    }

                }
                app.Documents.Save();
                app.Documents.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178792.aspx

Comment: Also, look here: http://alemiralles.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/how-to-replace-text-with-images-on-word.html

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl Thanks.. I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this:

```
var doc = app.Documents.add(path.GetFullPath(@"Docs/yourDoc.docx")), visible: false);
doc.Activate();
String textToReplace = "your text";
var selected = app.Selection;
selected.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", keyword);
selected.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceNone);
selected.Range.Select();

var imgPath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(yourImage))
selected.InLineShapes.AddPicture(FileName: imgPath, LinkToFile: false, SaveWithDocument: true);

doc.SaveAs(path.GetFullPath(@"Docs/yourDoc.docx"));
```